# Starcraft Brood War: How to remove limit of units?

Tags: starcraft

I would like to make a big map for Starcraft Brood War with lots of resources. How can I remove the unit limit 1650? i.e, there will not be "Cannot create more units" message. I tried to change the value in SCMDraft 2, but it didn't work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

That limit is in place due to the limitations of the game engine (and the requirement to run acceptably on weaker computers). Therefore it is impossible to remove this limit at all. For further information look [here](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Map_max).

Comment: Thank you. I understood that, and that is why I asked if there was a way to mod the engine, like the 1000 population mod for the Age of Empire The Conqueror.

Comment: @dh87 there might be a way to mod the game to use more units, however the game engine might not support it no matter how powerful your PC is. If I recall correctly, there used to be SC Total Conversions that had large amount of units, but not sure what the total was. Based on the unit cap, it looks like it's 200 x 8 (200 food x 8 players) + 50. It could be a cap set in place to control game performance issues in which case removing it should be possible.

Comment: If i recall correctly, there were mods which could increase this limit for older versions of SC. But such modifications became much harder to pull off with later versions of SC, since blizzard used newer compilers which apply more optimizations.